# Read HTML content into string

Tags: go

I have a html file in my project structure:
Both **/pkg** and **/html** are at the root level

**/html/sample.html**

I want to load this file into a string so that I can send it to an external service that sends an email with this html, which requires the html to be in a string format.

**/pkg/sender/sender.go**

```golang
if _, err := os.Stat("../../html/sample.html"); os.IsNotExist(err) {
    **// this happens**
    errors.New("The html template does not exist")
    fmt.Println("file does not exist")
}
```

Why is it saying that the file does not exist?

I want to then turn the contents of that file into a string

```golang
htmlBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("../../html/sample.html")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error parsing file")
    panic(err)
}
parsedHTML := string(htmlBytes)
```

Comment: Paths are relative to the [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), not the Go source file that uses the path.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Cerise pointed out, files in Go workspace are relative to working directory.

Here, try this.

```
 _, base, _, _ := runtime.Caller(0) // Relative to the runtime Dir
 dir := path.Join(path.Dir(base))
 rootDir := filepath.Dir(dir)

 // its better to use os specific path separator
 htmlDir := path.Join(rootDir, "html", "sample.html")
 htmlBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(htmlDir)
 // rest of your code.
```

You can read more about the runtime.Caller function [here](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Caller)